# Redirecting whole site to https via htaccess apart from specific pages

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have this code:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpe?g|gif|bmp|png|ico|js|css)$ [NC]
RewriteRule !^billing(/.*)?$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NC,NE]
```

This currently redirects anything outside of the *billing/* area to the `http` equivalent if they attempt to access it with `https`.

However I was wondering how I could go about adding additional pages to the "whitelist" of pages to be allowed to be loaded via `https`?

The two in question would be:

- http://www.mysite.com.au/remote/get_breaks.php
- http://www.mysite.com.au/thumbnail.php

However they both may have *query parameters* on the end.

Could someone explain how to add both the above as allowed to be accessed from `https` so I will know for next time I want to add something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to worry about the query string, those get matched outside of the request URI. You can add additional conditions:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpe?g|gif|bmp|png|ico|js|css)$ [NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/billing
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/remote/get_breaks\.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/thumbnail\.php

RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NC,NE]
```

makes it a little easier to read.

Comment: Thank you. So I don't need `(/.*)?$` at the end of the billing line? Will that still match `billing` with and without the slash? Also, I forgot to add, anything *inside* the `billing` directory must be allowed to be accessed by `https` and not just `billing/` itself. Currently that works, so just wanted to be sure this new code still allows that.

Comment: @Brett You don't need the `(/.*)?$`, it's pretty much the same thing. The only difference is that you require a `/` at the start of anything that comes after `/billing`, which you may need if you have files like: `/billing-foo.php` or something. The `^/billing` says "anything that **starts with** `/billing`"

Comment: Ok thanks. `billing` is a directory so don't really need to allow for things like `billing-foo.php` anyway. :)